# How to properly use nodejs soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, express, soap

My code looks like this:

```
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  if(err) {
     res.status(500);
     return res.send(err);
  }

  client.GetMemberPIN({pUserName: 'r'}, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
      res.status(500);
      return res.send(error)
    }
    return res.send(result);
  });
});
```

I tried running it and it returns this error?

```
{
  "code": "ECONNRESET"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest testing a few things:

- Make sure the url points to a valid WSDL document, e.g. https://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.CLS?WSDL=1
- Log which part of the process fails, e.g. the client creation, or the function call.

Here's a working example testing against a public server, this might help you to understand what could be going wrong with your code:

```
const soap = require('soap');
const url = 'https://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.CLS?WSDL=1';
const args = { id: 1 };

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error occurred creating client:", err);
        return;
    } 

    client.FindPerson(args, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("An error occurred calling client.FindPerson:", err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("client.FindPerson: response:", response);
    });
});
```

Comment: The url given to me ends with `/SOAP` without `?WSDL`. All of the examples I have searched ends with `?WSDL`. Does it have something to do with that? Also when I run the `client.GetServerDateTime()` it returns this `{
  "generatedMessage": false,
  "code": "ERR_ASSERTION",
  "actual": false,
  "expected": true,
  "operator": "=="
}`

Comment: Do you see the WSDL XML file at the url you're given? You could try appending ?WSDL to the url, that's worth a try.